# React Bootstrap - How to manually close OverlayTrigger

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an `OverlayTrigger` wrapping a `Popover` that contains some form inputs and a `Button` to save the data and close.

```
save(e) {
  this.setState({ editing: false })
  this.props.handleUpdate(e);
}

render() {
    return (
      <OverlayTrigger trigger="click"
        rootClose={true}
        onExit={this.save.bind(this) }
        show={this.state.editing}
        overlay={
            <Popover title="Time Entry">
              <FormGroup>
                    <ControlLabel>Data: </ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl type={'number'}/>
              </FormGroup>
              <Button onClick={this.save.bind(this) }>Save</Button>
           </Popover>
        }>
```

I have `rootClose = true`, and my callback gets executed `onExit`, but I don't see a way to manually close overlay.  I'm trying to use the `show` attribute from the Bootstrap `Modal` that (predictably) doesn't work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add a ref to the `<OverlayTrigger ref="overlay"...` element and call the `hide` method once the element has been rendered. Haven't tested it but should work:

```
this.refs.overlay.hide();
```

Comment: We have directive to avoid `ref`s where possible, but this works great.

Comment: This doesn't work with react-bootstrap 0.30.7 and react 15.4.2. Do you know how to accomplish this now?

Comment: I can't test this right now but It should work because the api still contains the hide method [https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v0.30.7/src/OverlayTrigger.js#L221], or you can try  with this one [https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v0.30.7/src/OverlayTrigger.js#L213]

Comment: For React 16, `.hide()` worked, but with different syntax. I had to use `<OverlayTrigger ref={(ref) => this.overlay = ref}>` and then call `this.overlay.hide();`.

Comment: Thanks... You just saved my day.

Comment: <OverlayTrigger ref={this.ref}> and then call this.ref.current.hide();

Comment: In functional components it should be ref.current.hide() right?

Comment: for functional component ref.current.hide() not working

Answer (score 53):

Hide function is not a public function on OverlayTrigger. Set `<OverlayTrigger rootClose={true}...` and then on your `onClick` event trigger call `document.body.click()`.

Comment: Very clever. Good answer.

Comment: I need to set a flag when the popover closes, does it have a close event which I can listen to and set my flag in its callback

Comment: this is not a solution when u have nested tooltip open

Answer (score 1):

If someone is searching for a solution without "close" button but rather -> close it on second click here it is:

```
    <OverlayTrigger trigger="focus" placement="top" overlay={popover}>
        <a tabindex="0">Some text</a>
    </OverlayTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Container,
  Popover,
  OverlayTrigger,
  Button,
  Row,
  Col
} from "react-bootstrap";

// Styles
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const PopoverCustom = () => {
  let ref = React.useRef(null);

  const popover = (
    <Popover id="popover-basic">
      {/* <Popover.Title as="h3">Popover right</Popover.Title> */}
      <Popover.Content>
        And here's some <strong>amazing</strong> content. It's very engaging.
        right?
        <div className="mt-3 mb-1">
          <Button
            onClick={() => ref.handleHide()}
            size="sm"
            variant="outline-dark"
            className="pt-0 pb-0"
          >
            Hide Popover
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
  );

  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      ref={r => (ref = r)}
      container={ref.current}
      trigger="click"
      placement="auto"
      overlay={popover}
      rootClose
    >
      <Button variant="dark">Show popover</Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Container className="ml-5 mt-5">
      <Row>
        <Col className="offset-sm-2" sm={8}>
          <PopoverCustom />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit React-Bootstrap Popover Dismiss]